# OpenGL filtering parameters and mipmap

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

When calling both

```java
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

and

```java
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

in the texture loading process in OpenGL, what will happen? What predominates, or what can I imagine what is going on in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), then the texture minifying function has to be `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`:
(See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml))

```java
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Note, `glGenerateMipmap` generates the mipmaps anyway. If the texture minifying is `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`, then the mipmaps are "ignored" on texture lookup.

If the minifying function is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and no mipmaps are generated, then the texture is not mipmap complete and texture access will return (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), in the shader program.

Comment: It should be noted, that even without using a mipmap filter, the mipmap levels might still be accessed during rendering, for example using the `textureLod` function in the shader. The filter and the contents of the mipmap pyramid are compltetely orthogonal.